# AS3 scope with function arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, scope

I find myself lacking knowledge around the below.

Take this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public var width:int = 10;
    public var height:int = 10;

    public function MyClass(width:int, height:int)
    {
        trace(width, height);
    }
}
```

The output will always be the supplied values for width and height, rather than the width and height properties that belong to `MyClass`. You will never receive an error for the above, either, even though it seems like there should be one for conflicting property names.

Why/how does this work? Also, are the width and height defined above my constructor still somehow accessible within my constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, because the parameter names "shadow" the field variable names, i.e. the compiler assumes you meant those.

You can access the members by using `this.width` and `this.height`.  This is also the de facto syntax the compiler converts all implicit member calls  to in byte code (if there were no local variable of the same name, `width` would automatically be translated to `this.width`).

BTW some IDEs, like FDT, allow you to set a warning or error message for name shadowing.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will give priority to locally scoped variables first.

In your case if you want the class member vars you will need to specify "this".

The parameters(width and height) are completely difference variables then the class members.